# Azure virtual machine rollback

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup, rollback

I've got a machine on Azure platform with Debian on it. It has some things installed and at this point I want to make a copy of it and do a few things, that may broke this installation. That's why I need a simple and fast option to rollback this machine to it's clean state.

Normally I would use snapshots, that would allow me to rollback the machine state with just one click, but it's not that simple as I thought. I've found a guide, where I had to do some complicated things with PowerShell, but I want to do it simply with new Azure portal.

I'm open to any oher methods, that would be simple and fast. I've checked backups, but it looks like there is only option to do scheduled and regular backups.

Does anyone knows an method, that would bring to me this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be - go to the disks properties and create a snapshot, that is if you are using managed disks.

Otherwise - use [this](https://www.petri.com/copy-virtual-hard-disk-microsoft-azure) article.

Comment: Do I need to have managed disk as a system disk on my VM? If yes, how could this be done?

Comment: Could you please add to your answer short guide how to make VM with menaged disk? I was looking for this, but I couldn't find that option when creating a new one or trying to edit existing machine.

Comment: on the settings screen (third one) when you create a vm there a button to select managed or unmanaged disk

Comment: Yeah, just found it by myself, thank you for answer!